# Integration of a given Integral

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, approximation

Given the integral

$$
\hat{\alpha}({r_{0}})=2\int^{\infty}_{{r_{0}}}\frac{dr}{r \sqrt{1-\frac{2M}{r}} \sqrt{\left(\frac{r}{{r_{0}}}\right)^{2}\left(1-\frac{2M}{{r_{0}}}\right) \left(1-\frac{2M}{r}\right)^{-1}-1}}
$$

The solution of the above integral we given [here](http://repository.ias.ac.in/5776/1/311.pdf), without shown how, to second order in Eq.(24) as

$$
\hat{\alpha}({r_{0}})=\frac{4M}{r_{0}}+\frac{4M^{2}}{r^{2}_{0}}\left(\frac{15\pi}{16}-2\right)+....
$$

Could someone please show me how to get this result?

Comment: so we may assume that $M/r_0$ is small?

Comment: Yes, you may. $r_{0}$ is bigger than $M$.